# Attributeerror-module-pil-image-has-no-attribute-antialias

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, easyocr

I am working on Automatic Number plate detection problem using opencv and yolo.
I am getting the below error when i pass the numpy array to easyocr readtext module

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)

print(type(license_plate_crop)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(license_plate_crop)
detections = reader.readtext(license_plate_crop)
```

This is the error i am getting

```
line 619, in get_image_list
    crop_img,ratio = compute_ratio_and_resize(crop_img,width,height,model_height)
  File "/home/pranith_dev/Desktop/Datavoice/Automatic-License-Plate-Recognition-using-YOLOv8/dev-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/easyocr/utils.py", line 582, in compute_ratio_and_resize
    img = cv2.resize(img,(int(model_height*ratio),model_height),interpolation=Image.ANTIALIAS)
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'
```

I tried downgrading pillow version from  10.0.0 to 9.5 or 9.4 according to online solutions but the issue still persists and the following is the output

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 ...
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ... 255 255 255]]
Illegal instruction
```

Comment: why are you passing a PIL constant to an OpenCV function? or rather, why does easyocr appear to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Pranith !

The [EasyOCR project](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) on Github lists a commit to `utils.py`: [Update utils.py](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR/commit/caf88774f673774079c681d77d2314c986431104). Apparently, `Image.Resampling.LANCZOS` replaced `PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS` in Pillow 10.

You can check your own Pillow version with `pip list | grep pillow`.
Make sure you have:

- either the EasyOCR version which includes the mentioned commit (and still compatible with Python `3.10`, which you are using)
- or keep your EasyOCR version but downgrade your Pillow version accordingly, so that it has `PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS`

Comment: `Image.ANTIALIAS` and `Image.Resampling.LANCZOS` coexisted in many versions of Pillow, looks like they finally removed the deprecated one.

Comment: I just tested my own copy of PIL 9.3.0, and it returns the following warning for `Image.ANTIALIAS`: `Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1
DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.`

Comment: that's a PIL constant, it has no business being passed to an OpenCV function... EasyOCR seems broken

Comment: i tried both approaches but is not working and giving same error.